# Hosting a WCF service in a unit test

Tags: wcf, unit-testing

I'm wanting to unit test my custom `ServiceHostFactory`.  Unfortunately, I get this `InvalidOperationException` when calling `CreateServiceHost`:

> 'ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment. This API requires that the calling application be hosted in IIS or WAS.

I can work around this by refactoring my class such that it exposes a public method that can be directly invoked by the unit test instead of using its inherited public interface; I hate to change my interface just for the sake of a unit test.  I also see another SO answer that recommends spawning a Cassini host, but I'd hate to complicate my unit tests in this manner.

Is there a way to work around this `ServiceHostFactory` limitation without resorting to these measures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  In my custom `ServiceHostFactory`, I had only overridden the protected method, `CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)`.  By overriding the public `CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)` method, I was able to construct the service host factory with no issues.

Before:

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return this.CreateServiceHost(typeof(MyService), baseAddresses);
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this problem (I am not 100% sure whether we should be doing this).

In the set up of the unit test fixture, set up a hosting environment (NUnit example):

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void TestFixtureSetup()
{
    if(!HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        // The instance constructor hooks up the singleton hosting environment, ewww...
        new HostingEnvironment();

        // Check the hosting environment is fully initialized
        ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

Then you should be free to use your custom `ServiceHostFactory` from inside of your unit tests:

```
[Test]
public void ServiceHostIsCorrect()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceType = typeof (string);
    var factory = new UnityServiceHostFactory();

    // Act
    var serviceHost = factory.CreateServiceHost(serviceType.AssemblyQualifiedName, new Uri[] {});

    // Assert
    Expect(serviceHost, Is.TypeOf<UnityServiceHost>());
    var unityServiceHost = (UnityServiceHost)serviceHost;
    Expect(unityServiceHost.Description.ServiceType, Is.EqualTo(serviceType));
}
```